# Build ffmpeg using yocto

Tags: build, ffmpeg, yocto

I am trying to build ffmpeg for an ARM SoC. Therefore I am using yocto with following recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "FFMPEG"
HOMEPAGE = "http://ffmpeg.org"

LICENSE = "GPLv2"
#LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING.GPLv2"

#SECTION = "net"
#DEPENDS = "sqlite3-native glib-2.0 zlib libpcre spawn-fcgi fcgi"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

SRC_URI = "git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git;branch=release/2.8 \
        "


PACKAGECONFIG[--build] = ""

EXTRA_OECONF = " \
             --extra-ldflags=-static \
             --extra-cflags=-static \
             --disable-mipsfpu \
             --disable-mips32r2 \
             --disable-mipsdspr1 \
             --disable-mipsdspr2 \
             --enable-bzlib \
             --enable-zlib \
"

inherit autotools pkgconfig
```

Building this recipe throws following errer:

```
Unknown option "--build=x86_64-linux`
```

How can I remove this configuration flag from do_configure?
Or is there any other way to build `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using yocto (as you said) it would be best to simply include the `ffmpeg` package in your image using:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "ffmpeg"
```

This should work because `ffmpeg` is available in the `poky` repository.

If you need a specific version of `ffmpeg`, IMHO it is the best way to adapt [the available recipe](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-multimedia/ffmpeg) to your needs.